# Monogame - How to properly cap FPS in Monogame?

Tags: xna, windows-phone-8.1, monogame

I wanted to cap FPS of my game at 30fps conditionally if being built for Windows Phone, as I don't need it to be running at 60fps on it and I heard from too many it is better to have it capped on mobile device because of battery draining.

I used same snippet of code used by XNA for Windows Phone 7:

```
//FrameRate is 30fps by default for WindowsPhone.
TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
```

But... As it is doing its job capping FPS, it is affecting everything else too, causing stuttering and sound issues. Because of this, I suppose I'm doing something wrong.

Anything which would help me would be great, as I was not able to find anything on the internet regarding this issue (most people wanted quite the opposite :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your sound issues look into multi-threading and running your sound system on a separate, uncapped thread. For the game code, specifically the code that updates your assets, your method should work, but personally I do it differently.

```
// in your game1 class variable definitions
private const float timeToNextUpdate = 1.0f / 30.0f;
private float timeSinceLastUpdate;

//in your game1 update method
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    timeSinceLastUpdate += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    if (timeSinceLastUpdate >= timeToNextUpdate)
    {
        //update game
        timeSinceLastUpdate = 0;
    }
    //systems you don't want to limit would be updated here
}
```

Comment: I think I'm quite late by now to reply to you (sorry about that, I created account back than and didn't logged in since :/ ). Although I would do this through threads nowadays, your approach seems reasonable too (and definitely safer than dealing with threads).
I'll mark this ancient question as answered :)